# Unable to evaluate ClojureScript using fireplace.vim when using the Clojure CLI

Tags: vim, clojurescript, vim-plugin

I was looking forward to experimenting with [the new release of ClojureScript](https://clojurescript.org/news/2018-03-26-clojurescript-command-line) but I'm running into a problem when trying to evaluate code.

I have an nREPL server running and am (seemingly?) able to connect to it using `:Fireplaceconnect localhost:$PORT`. However, when I try to evaluate code (using either `:Eval` or `:CljsEval`) I see an error message which says, "Fireplace: no default ClojureScript REPL".

There's [an issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/issues/372) in the fireplace.vim repository which mentions this problem, but it was closed with RTFM -- I have and I still can't figure out a solution.

#### ~/.clojure/deps.edn

```
{
  :aliases {:nREPL
             {:extra-deps
               {nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "0.7.0"}
                cider/piggieback {:mvn/version "0.4.2"}}}}
}
```

#### starting nrepl

```
> clj -R:nREPL -m nrepl.cmdline --middleware "[cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]"
```

Comment: It doesnt look like your alias requires clojurescript: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/30d1bb7439ee21789d8909e764a516b57bac149f/links/clojure/deps.edn#L31

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried adding that entry to my alias and as a global dependency and it doesn't change anything. Also, for whatever it's worth, my alias was taken directly from the Piggieback docs. How are you using the aliases you've defined in your linked deps.edn?

Comment: Tbh i havent worked with a clojurescript fireplace connection in several months (though my regular clojure fireplace connection, which is just above, has gotten a good workout lately).

Comment: Not sure it solves your problem, but at least it got rid of the `Fireplace: no default ClojureScript REPL` for me. Start the repl as described here: https://github.com/nrepl/piggieback and enter: `(require 'cljs.repl.node)` then in vim you can do `:CljEval  (cider.piggieback/cljs-repl (cljs.repl.node/repl-env))`

Comment: Thanks for that @SebastianBlask. I eventually hit upon that same solution. Interestingly, I was then running into a problem caused by trying to use Figwheel and the new `:bundle` feature, but a new release was cut this week which is supposed to address those issues. I may update my question or, if you'd like, you could add your suggestion as an answer and I'd consider accepting it because it does solve the question as it stands. :)

Comment: I am not in it for the points ;-) If you get the whole thing to work you can write an answer as a reference. I am yet to find solution to develop Clojurescript in vim/fireplace that actually works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workable solution and have documented the entire workflow [here](https://github.com/ethagnawl/clojurescript-vim-fireplace-demo):

deps.edn:

```
{
 :aliases {:rebel {:main-opts ["-m" "rebel-readline.main"]}}
 :paths ["src" "resources" "target"]
 :deps {cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.25.0-alpha1"}
        cider/piggieback {:mvn/version "0.5.0"}
        com.bhauman/figwheel-main {:mvn/version "0.2.6"}
        com.bhauman/rebel-readline {:mvn/version "0.1.4"}
        com.bhauman/rebel-readline-cljs {:mvn/version "0.1.4"}
        nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "0.7.0"}
        org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.10.1"}
        org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.773"}
        reagent {:mvn/version "0.10.0"
                 :exclusions [cljsjs/react cljsjs/react-dom]}}}
```

Inside a Clojure REPL run the following commands to start the nREPL server, ClojureScript REPL and Figwheel build:

```
(require '[fullstack.helpers :refer :all])  ;; import nREPL helpers
(start-nrepl-server!)                       ;; start nREPL server on 7888

;; Some people run the following commands using Vim-Fireplace's `:CljEval`
;; command but I found that to be a little clunky.
;; If I do end up using this workflow regularly, I'll consider packaging these
;; steps up in a VimScript helper function.
;; Out of habit, I send them from this document inside vim to a parallel tmux
;; pane using vim-slime.

(require 'figwheel.main.api)    ;; require Figwheel's scripting API
(figwheel.main.api/start "dev") ;; start Figwheel build (using dev.cljs.edn) and REPL
```

Within Vim, run the following command in the CLI prompt (hit `:` in command mode) in order to connect to the running ClojureScript REPL:

```
:Piggieback (figwheel.main.api/repl-env "dev") " connect to the CLJS REPL
```

The major differences are moving the dependencies to the local deps.edn (this is not necessary, but I think it's a better, more flexible approach), upgrading Piggieback and leaning on the higher level Figwheel scripting API, instead of CLI flags.